# Is it possible to share some code between several pages in Node.js like with PHP without using pug or ejs?

Tags: node.js

I want to include a header, a menu and a footer in my web app for most of the pages but I don't want to write the same code in every pages. I know this is possible with PHP, but I'm using Node.js and I can't use jade/pug or EJS. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you would create your files that contain your content like the following two file here:

**header.js**

```js
module.exports = `<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</nav>`
```

**footer.js**

```js
module.exports = `<footer>
  <!-- Your footer code -->
</footer>`
```

Next within your app, you would listen for a request and then just require the files, and concatenate the data to generate a new string `header + body + footer`, then you would write that out to the response. I am not sure how you will be getting your body, but here is an example:

**main.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const header = require('./header.js');
const footer = require('./footer.js');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  // Get the body somehow
  // We will just use a switch here and test `req.url`
  let bodyFile = './home.js';
  switch(req.url) {
    case '/about': bodyFile = './about.js'; break;
    case '/contact': bodyFile = './contact.js'; break;
  }

  const body = require(bodyFile);

  res.write(header + body + footer);
  res.end();
});

server.listen(8000);
```